# Why is no TransactionRequiredException thrown when @Transactional is missing?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I've got a Spring/JPA configuration with Hibernate as the persistence provider. However I don't understand why there's no TransactionRequiredException thrown when I call save() on the following DAO code without an open transaction (there's no @Transactional at the DAO/service):

```
@Repository
public class UserDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void save(User user) {
        entityManager.persist(user);
    }
}
```

As expected the entity is not saved but why is there no exception thrown? The [javadoc for persist](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) says that persist() should throw a "TransactionRequiredException - if there is no transaction when invoked on a container-managed entity manager of that is of type PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION".

Debugging shows that Hibernate has an open session. Is that the expected behavior? BTW: I get the same behavior when using EclipseLink.

Here's my applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo.bar" />
<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven />

<!-- Configure jdbc.properties -->
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<!-- Data Source configuration -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="HSQL" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

**EDIT**
Hibernate version (from pom.xml)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is pretty clear and concise (you actually discovered it yourself): JPA requires a transaction being in progress for the call to `EntityManager.persist(…)`. However your code is not set up to be run inside a transaction. Your configuration looks sane but you're missing an `@Transactional` on either the DAO or any layer above.

As the original question was why the exception is not thrown, I looked up the spec again and discovered that in 7.9.1 it clearly requires the container to throw that exception in a container managed persistence context. Running JPA in Spring is a bit of an in-between scenario, as we clearly don't require JTA and the like but it's understandable that by injecting the `EntityManager` you assume to be in a managed environment. I filed [SPR-11923](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11923) to improve that in our JPA infrastructure support.

Side track: When working with Spring and JPA, you might wanna have a look at the [Spring Data JPA project](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/), which significantly eases the process of building a data access layer, including sane defaults for transaction processing on the repository layer (see this [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) for example). Using that would've prevented you from running into the situation in the first place.

Comment: Yes its true that the code is (intentionally, to show the situation) not set up in a transaction, so I don't expect the entity to be saved in the database. But why is no exception thrown? Thanks for your response & the link to Spring Data JPA!

Comment: Which Hibernate version are you using?

Comment: I've added the version information. BTW the same happens with EclipseLink.

Comment: Added some additional observations in a second paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc states that an exception is expected "if there is no transaction when invoked on a container-managed entity manager of that is of type PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION"
Your context is managed by Spring which I don't believe is a Java EE container, and so the same rule does not apply, and the context is probably defaulting to extended so that it holds objects until joined to a transaction.  If you want to force an exception when a transaction isn't available, call em.flush() after the persist.

Comment: I think, one should use a JTA transaction manager + a JTA data-source for that EntityManager and then it could work (despite of fact that Tomcat (+Spring) is not a JEE container).

Comment: I'd defer to you on that.  My answer should have been put as a comment as I am unfamiliar with spring settings and defaults.  My understanding was though you can use a transaction controller without being container managed.

Comment: Well, my comment is only an assumption, as I do not use Spring (with that configuration).

Comment: @Chris sure em.flush() forces the exception. I'm just wondering about the underlying reason why the exception isn't thrown by default and why Spring shows a different behavior than stated in the javadoc of the JPA entitymanager.

Comment: @John did you try what I proposed?

Comment: @AndreiI I'm going to try it (currently fiddling around with the config), but I though JTA should be used for distributed transactions or when using the JEE container as the transaction coordinator? ([see here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/jta/JtaTransactionManager.html))